# Is there a way to create a loop inside a case statement on vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I would like to know if there is a way to create a loop inside a case statement in vhdl.

Currently I have this code

```
    CASE A1 IS 
        WHEN "00000" => RD1 <= REG0;
        WHEN "00001" => RD1 <= REG1;
        WHEN "00010" => RD1 <= REG2;
        WHEN "00011" => RD1 <= REG3;
        WHEN "00100" => RD1 <= REG4;
        WHEN "00101" => RD1 <= REG5;
        WHEN "00110" => RD1 <= REG6;
        WHEN "00111" => RD1 <= REG7;
        WHEN "01000" => RD1 <= REG8;
        WHEN "01001" => RD1 <= REG9;
        WHEN "01010" => RD1 <= REG10;
        WHEN "01011" => RD1 <= REG11;
        WHEN "01100" => RD1 <= REG12;
        WHEN "01101" => RD1 <= REG13;
        WHEN "01110" => RD1 <= REG14;
        WHEN "01111" => RD1 <= REG15;
        WHEN "10000" => RD1 <= REG16;
        WHEN "10001" => RD1 <= REG17;
        WHEN "10010" => RD1 <= REG18;
        WHEN "10011" => RD1 <= REG19;
        WHEN "10100" => RD1 <= REG20;
        WHEN "10101" => RD1 <= REG21;
        WHEN "10110" => RD1 <= REG22;
        WHEN "10111" => RD1 <= REG23;
        WHEN "11000" => RD1 <= REG24;
        WHEN "11001" => RD1 <= REG25;
        WHEN "11010" => RD1 <= REG26;
        WHEN "11011" => RD1 <= REG27;
        WHEN "11100" => RD1 <= REG28;
        WHEN "11101" => RD1 <= REG29;
        WHEN "11110" => RD1 <= REGZLO;
        WHEN "11111" => RD1 <= REGZHI;
        WHEN OTHERS => RD1 <= (OTHERS => '0');
     END CASE;
```

As you can see the only thing that changes from one statement to the next is the number of the REG asigned to RD1. Couldn't the fact that it always matches the value of A1 (except on the last 2 cases but those can be done separately) be used to make a loop so that all the statements don't have to be written?

Thank you.

Comment: Make your REG one dimension bigger and then use A1 as index.

Comment: Yes you can. It won't solve this specific problem, for which Oldfart's comment is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a loop inside a case statement

No, you can not, at least not in the way I think you want to do it.

It would not make sense because if you can use a loop you can use the loop variable as selector/index or you can derive the value from it.

A `case` is intended for non-regular and/or sparse selection.

---

You can of course place a loop inside a case like this:

```
WHEN "01100" => for ...
```

But I am pretty sure that is not what you where referring to.

Comment: A case statement uses static values of the case expression to exclusively select a sequence of statements to execute (control flow). A sequence of statements is one or more sequential statements, including assignment statements (making the OP case statement valid while being neither "non-regular" nor "sparse" noting all values of a case expression must be represented once and only once). Your rationale doesn't fit VHDL case statements nor syntax.

Comment: As Brian commented your basic idea is valid, instead of "...I think you want ..." you could ask for clarification so there's no guessing involved in what question is being answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Why have 30 different signals when 1 will do?
type reg_a is array(0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(?? downto 0);
signal reg_s : reg_a;

-- Don't use a loop when you can just index into an array
if (unsigned(A1) < 30) then
    RD1 <= reg_s(TO_INTEGER(unsigned(A1)));
else if (A1 = "11110") then
    RD1 <= REGZLO;
else
   RD1 <= REGZHI;
end if;
```

Comment: It's generally recommended to add an explanation outside of the code in answers. If you do that, you may receive an upvote instead of a downvote.

Comment: I thought if statements couldn't be used ouside of processes and I'm trying to make a combinational entity.